# mvn docker:stop not called after integration test

Tags: maven, docker-compose, maven-failsafe-plugin, docker-maven-plugin

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
      <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
        <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.23.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <keepContainer>false</keepContainer>
          <removeVolumes>true</removeVolumes>
          <images>
            <image>
              <alias>zookeeper</alias>
              <name>jplock/zookeeper:3.4.6</name>
              <run>
                <ports>
                  <port>2181:2181</port>
                </ports>
                <log>
                  <prefix>ZOOKEEPER</prefix>
                  <color>yellow</color>
                </log>
              </run>
            </image>
            <image>
              <alias>kafka</alias>
              <name>wurstmeister/kafka:1.0.0</name>
              <run>
                <links>
                  <link>zookeeper:zookeeper</link>
                </links>
                <ports>
                  <port>9092:9092</port>
                </ports>
                <env>
                  <KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME>127.0.0.1</KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME>
                  <KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT>9092</KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT>
                  <KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS>test:3:1</KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS>
                  <KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT>zookeeper:2181</KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT>
                  <KAFKA_BROKER_ID>999</KAFKA_BROKER_ID>
                </env>
                <log>
                  <prefix>KAFKA</prefix>
                  <color>yellow</color>
                </log>
              </run>
            </image>
          </images>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>start</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>build</goal>
              <goal>start</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>stop</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>stop</goal>
              <goal>remove</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.20.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <environmentVariables>
            <KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME>127.0.0.1</KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME>
            <KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT>9092</KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT>
            <KAFKA_TOPICS>test</KAFKA_TOPICS>
            <KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS>test:3:1</KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS>
            <KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT>zookeeper:2181</KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT>
            <KAFKA_BROKER_ID>999</KAFKA_BROKER_ID>
          </environmentVariables>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

After running `mvn integration-test`, I found the docker containers still running by `docker ps`. I have to run `mvn docker:stop` to stop and remove them manually. But `mvn verify` can stop and remove docker containers automatically. Why? Anyone can help? Thanks

Comment: The reason is simple cause you should run `mvn clean verify`  instead of `mvn clean integration-test` cause using the last one the `post-integration-test`phase is not run and will not execute the docker part to stop the container...

Comment: @khmarbaise thanks.